# (MapView) Userlocation image changed help to restore

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotation

I am working with MapKit and I changed the Annotation´s image, but the problem is, the Userlocation (blue dot) also changed its picture (I didn't want that). How can I restore it back to normal. Also, I added a small button to the callout which (as you may have guessed) was added to my location and it was not supposed to be there. My code is the following...

```
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if !(annotation is MKUserLocation) {
            print("annotation is MKUserLocation")
        }
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: "identifier")
            if annotationView == nil{
                annotationView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "identifier")
                annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
                annotationView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = UIButton(type: .detailDisclosure)

                let pinImg = UIImage(named: "curz")
                let size = CGSize(width: 50, height: 50)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)
                pinImg!.draw(in: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height))
                let resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                annotationView!.image = resizedImage
                }
        else {
        annotationView!.annotation = annotation
      }
    return annotationView
   }

        //Var SelectedAnnotation
        var anotacionSeleccionada : MKPointAnnotation!

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        anotacionSeleccionada = view.annotation as? MKPointAnnotation
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "vista", sender: self)
        }
      }


    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let destination = segue.destination as? ViewController {
        destination.pin = anotacionSeleccionada
       }
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `viewFor annotation` function add this row in the beginning:

```
if annotation is MKUserLocation {
   return nil
}
```

Because you don´t want to do anything if it´s the `MKUserLocation`.

Comment: Do I put that line instead of "if !(annotation is MKUserLocation)" ?

Comment: Yes you can @DanielC.

Comment: Only one question, is it normal for the Userlocation not to appear in the simulator but appear when I use it in the phone?

Comment: The simulator could bug sometimes when using locations, but normally it should work.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I will accept your answer in a couple of minutes (it says 7 minutes have passed to accept answers, maybe is because my score (reputation) tho.

Comment: I know I´m asking a lot of questions but, do you mind if I ask you what the function is really doing? I got my code from Internet and I still got some doubts, like for example what is that "Identifier" or dequeReusable... method and reuseIdentifier. I thank you in advance :)

Comment: That function sets the view for you annotation (the default red pin). `dequeueReusableAnnotationView identifier` is used to identify the annotation.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it, I checked your answer. Is there any place I can get more information about functions and methods for development?. I´m kind of new to iOS.

Comment: I can recommend reading Apples documentation for Swift, that´s a good start and when you´re working in Xcode you can hold ALT + click on a function to read more about it.

Comment: Np glad to help. Helped you answer your question with custom images if you want to checkout my example too and get some inspiration even though you have implemented it. Good luck with your coding!